# Preventing Automatic ivar Synthesis of @property

Tags: objective-c, properties, instance-variables, synthesize

I have `readonly` properties that I would like to declare similarly to other properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyThing *thing;
```

Frequently, I definitely **do not** want an instance variable and getter method to be automatically synthesised for these properties. In such cases I have made an error if I forget to write an explicit getter for them, and I want the compiler to tell me and refuse to compile (or at least, issue a warning).

In such cases, is it bad practice to use a `@property` declaration? Should I instead use:

```
-(MyThing*) myThing;
```

Or, alternatively, is there some way that I can tell `@property` in the attributes list `(nonatomic, readonly, dont_synthesize_this_one_please)` that I definitely don't want an instance variable to be sythesized and it's an error if I've missed out the getter?

Comment: You could declare those properties in a protocol and then make your class conform to that protocol. Auto property synthesis will not synthesize properties declared in a protocol and will warn you about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no special attribute. If you don't overwrite the getter, the ivar will be synthesized.

Making the property a normal method as you suggest is the best solution.
You could also experiment with turning on the following compiler warning:

[image: Implicit Synthesized Properties]

but then you will get warnings for ALL the synthesized properties.

You can also turn it on for every file separately `-Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis`

Comment: Great – thanks. Nice to know about the warning, but I'll avoid as I generally appreciate the synthesised ivars.